# bluebird promisifyAll() and then() not working together with node require

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I'm using Promises for the first time, so please bear with me.

Basically, I'm not seeing the function in my `.then()` statement being called.

When I call `t.t()`, is it working correctly.

When I call `t.tAsync()`, `t()` is again called.

However the result isn't being passed into the then when I call `t.tAync().then(console.log);`

Here is my node module:

```
'use strict';
var t = function(){
    console.log('inside t()');
    return 'j';
};

module.exports = {
    t: t
};
```

And here is my demo script:

```
'use strict';

require('should');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var t = require('../src/t');

Promise.promisifyAll(t);

/*
    Call t() once to demonstrate.
    Call tAsync() and see t() is called
    Call tAsync.then(fn), and then isn't called


 */


// this works as expected, calling t()
console.log('calling t()...' + t.t());

// this also works, calling t()
t.tAsync();

// the then() statement isn't called
t.tAsync().then(function(res){
    // I expect this to be called
    console.log('HHHUUUZZZAAAHHH' + res);
});


/*
    Keep the script running 5 seconds
 */

(function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('finished program');
    }, i * 1000)
})(5);
```

And here is the output from the test:

```
inside t()
calling t()...j
inside t()
inside t()
finished program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `then` clause will never be called because the `tAsync` is expecting `t` to call the callback not return a value.

`promisifyAll` wraps Node.JS aysynchronous API's so the function it is wrapping needs to conform to the Node.JS callback signature:

```
function t(callback) {
  callback(null, 'j');
}
```

However, I suspect based on your code that you do not want `promiseifyAll` but instead `try()` or `method()`:

```
function t() {
  return 'j';
}

Promise.try(t).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

**OR**

```
var t = Promise.method(function() {
  return 'j';
});

t().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

For contrast the above is [Bluebird.js](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) specific. To perform this with generic Promises you would approach it one of two ways:

Using the Promise constructor:

```
function t() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('j');
  });
}

t().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Or, use the `then` chaining feature:

```
function t() {
  return 'j';
}

Promise.resolve()
  .then(t)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Sukima. That's exactly what I was looking for.
It felt like I was missing something, and I was!

Comment: Just to clarify the I wrote the answer in the spirit that `t()` was more then just returning a value. If it was just returning a value this entire process could be simplified to `Promise.resolve('j').then(…)`.

Comment: This took me two days to find - i thought it might behave similar to async / await. The bluebird js docs could really use this example.

Answer (score 0):

I was also not able to understand how "then" works. Below code example (just created to understand the flow) may help you:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function task1(callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("taks1");
        callback(null, "taks1");
    }, 2000);
}

var taks1Async = Promise.promisify(task1);

taks1Async().then(function(result) {
    console.log("Current task2, previous: " + result);
    return "task2";
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("Current task3, previous: " + result);
    return "task3";
})
.catch(function(e) {
    console.log("error: " + e);
});

console.log("Finished");
```